# How to map each item from several lists into the object in Java without using for loops

Tags: java, automation, mapping

I have 3 lists which describe user: status, name, email. I need to put each elements from each list into an object(e.g get each first element from each list and put them into UserItem and add object to list, so it describes my 1st user and so on). I use following solution, but I want to know is there any design pattern to solve this in more efficient way? I want to avoid classic for loops(ive tried to find solution using stream api, but vainly).

```
    public List<UserItem> mapToObject(final List<String> statusList, final List<String> nameList, final List<String> emailList) {

    for (int i = 0; i < emailList.size(); i++) {
        var item = new UserItem();
        item.setStatus(statusList.get(i));
        item.setName(nameList.get(i));
        item.setEmail(emailList.get(i));
        setItem(item);
    }
    return getItems();
}
```

Comment: maybe lambda statements might be useful here (`forEach` loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making objects using data gathered from lists or any kind of array type data objects, you need looping, so you should use for loop, while loop or as in comments the `forEach` loop.

If you need some design pattern answer I'll go with using an iterator for each list.

```
public List<UserItem> mapToObject(final List<String> statusList, final List<String> nameList, final List<String> emailList) {

    List<UserItem> users = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator statusIt = statusList.iterator();
    Iterator nameIt = nameList.iterator();
    Iterator emailIt = emailList.iterator();

    while (statusIt.hasNext() && nameIt.hasNext() && emailIt.hasNext()) {
        UserItem item = new UserItem();
        item.setStatus((String)statusIt.next());
        item.setName((String)nameIt.next());
        item.setEmail((String)emailIt.next());
        users.add(item);
    }
    return users;
}
```